# SELECT all rows with sequential id after a specific id

Tags: mysql, select, sequence

Is it possible to query all rows that their `id`s are sequential after a specific `id`? (`id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.)

For example, suppose my specific id is **`5`**. Then I want all rows with these `id`s:

**`6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, ... `until this sequence exists`**. E.g. if there is no row with `id=12` then the sequence must be stopped at `11`. So desired result would be *rows with these `id`s*:

**`6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`.**

I use MySQL.

---

EDIT:

## An example:

This is my table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Inheritance ORDER BY id ASC;                     
+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
| classNS     | class             | super      | superNS     | id    |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
|             | Data              | Object     |             | 00002 |
|             | Thing             | Object     |             | 00003 |
| BUILD       | DATA              | Data       |             | 00004 |
|             | Dialable          | Data       |             | 00005 |
|             | Phone             | Data       |             | 00006 |
|             | Email             | Data       |             | 00007 |
|             | Place             | Data       |             | 00008 |
|             | Website           | Data       |             | 00009 |
|             | SocialNetworkLink | Data       |             | 00011 |
|             | Password          | Data       |             | 00012 |
|             | User              | Thing      |             | 00013 |
|             | Asset             | Thing      |             | 00014 |
|             | Collection        | Asset      |             | 00015 |
|             | Product           | Asset      |             | 00016 |
| collections | School            | Collection |             | 00017 |
| collections | LangSchool        | Collection |             | 00018 |
| BUILD       | OWNER             | DATA       | BUILD       | 00022 |
| BUILD       | OWNER_OF_PRODUCT  | DATA       | BUILD       | 00023 |
| BUILD       | OWNER_OF_EMAIL    | DATA       | BUILD       | 00024 |
| BUILD       | COUNTRY           | DATA       | BUILD       | 00025 |
| BUILD       | SOCIAL_NETWORK    | DATA       | BUILD       | 00026 |
| BUILD       | PROVINCE_IR       | DATA       | BUILD       | 00027 |
| collections | SchoolPlus        | School     | collections | 00028 |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+-------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I want this result (when my specific `id` is `5`):

```
+---------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
| classNS | class    | super | superNS | id    |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
|         | Phone    | Data  |         | 00006 |
|         | Email    | Data  |         | 00007 |
|         | Place    | Data  |         | 00008 |
|         | Website  | Data  |         | 00009 |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+-------+
```

*Notice that the row with `id=10` is absent in the source table.*

Answer (score 2):

A query that doesn't use recursive CTEs or window functions or variables:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM Inheritance AS i
    JOIN
    ( SELECT ui.id 
      FROM Inheritance AS ui
      WHERE ui.id > 5
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1
              FROM Inheritance AS pi
              WHERE pi.id = ui.id - 1
            ) 
      ORDER BY ui.id
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS up
    ON  i.id < up.id
WHERE i.id > 5 ;
```

Comment: If you are in version 8.0 and you cna use the window function solution, it will probably be more efficient than this. But test! There is nothing better than testing performance of all the suggested solutions -in your setup and with your data (size, distribution matter).

Comment: I could understand the logic. Isn't better to write `WHERE pi.id = ui.id - 1 LIMIT 1` instead of just: `WHERE pi.id = ui.id - 1`? Seems this way we can prevent some extra explorations.

Comment: No, inside a `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` subquery, LIMIT 1 does nothing. As soon as 1 matching row is found, it doesn't search for more anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot of things, instead of just my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a recursive CTE in MySQL-8.0+ or MariaDB-10.2+

```
with recursive prior as (
select * from num where i = 5
union
select n.*
from num n
join prior on prior.i+1=n.i
)
select * from prior;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=651d136e4c1b2b935a40682b6e272b87)

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the `Tabibitosan Method` can be adjusted for any RDBMS that supports `analytic` functions.

Article for the Oracle version:  https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-915680

The concept uses analytic functions to identify groups of incremental gap free values.

`value - row_number() over (order by ____)` is constant for a group of sequential gap free numbers.  Each value (of this calculation) represents a unique group of consecutive values.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with straight-up SQL - in mySQL version 8 onwards, using the row_number() function.

Also - it doesn't matter if your target ID does not exist in the table (ie. the value '5' in your question - this solution will work whether or not you have '5' in your table).

If you want to see how the row_number() function is used to determine whether a row should be kept in the result set or not, uncomment the two columns I have added that help illustrate the logic, then run the inner SELECT statement on its own.

```
select workingTable.id from
(
  select 
    id,
--    id - 5 as idCheck, -- update the '5' here. this column is unnecessary for the solution
--    row_number() over w as rowNum, -- this column is unnecessary for the solution
    (id - 5) - (row_number() over w) as checkVal -- update the 5 here
from myTable
where id > 5 -- and update the 5 here
window w as (order by id)
  ) as workingTable
where workingTable.checkVal = 0
;
```

Here is the DDL to create and populate the table:

```
create table myTable (id int);

insert into myTable (id) values (4);
insert into myTable (id) values (5);
insert into myTable (id) values (6);
insert into myTable (id) values (7);
insert into myTable (id) values (8);
insert into myTable (id) values (9);
insert into myTable (id) values (10);
insert into myTable (id) values (11);
insert into myTable (id) values (13);
insert into myTable (id) values (14);
```

And here is [the db-fiddle to test](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wFCShZbMaShLnP3S39gyLt/0).

Here is the same solution, without comments and unnecessary columns, in more compact format:

```
select workingTable.id from
(   select 
    (id - 5) - (row_number() over w) as checkVal -- update
    from myTable
    where id > 5 -- update
    window w as (order by id)
    ) as workingTable
where workingTable.checkVal = 0
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way: This works. But I don't know is reliable or not (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16715618/5318303)):

```
SET @id = 5;

SELECT *
FROM table_name
FORCE KEY (id)
WHERE id = @id + 1 AND @id := @id + 1
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

*Or better is to initiate `@id` with `5+1` and then use `@id` instead of `@id+1` in comparison (`WHERE id=@id AND ...`).*

---

You can't write `WHERE` clause like below (I don't know why):

```
WHERE id = (@id := @id+1)
```

UPDATE:

See unexpected result (!) (according to the sample table in the question):

```
mysql> SET @id = 5;                                                              
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                                             

mysql> SELECT * FROM Inheritance FORCE KEY (id) WHERE id = (@id := @id+1) ORDER BY id ASC;                                                                        
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------+-------+                
| classNS     | class            | super  | superNS     | id    |                
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------+-------+                
| BUILD       | OWNER            | DATA   | BUILD       | 00022 |                
| BUILD       | OWNER_OF_PRODUCT | DATA   | BUILD       | 00023 |                
| BUILD       | OWNER_OF_EMAIL   | DATA   | BUILD       | 00024 |                
| BUILD       | COUNTRY          | DATA   | BUILD       | 00025 |                
| BUILD       | SOCIAL_NETWORK   | DATA   | BUILD       | 00026 |                
| BUILD       | PROVINCE_IR      | DATA   | BUILD       | 00027 |                
| collections | SchoolPlus       | School | collections | 00028 |                
+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------+-------+                
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)                                                         

mysql> SELECT @id;                                                               
+------+                                                                         
| @id  |                                                                         
+------+                                                                         
|   28 |                                                                         
+------+                                                                         
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Or (when `@id` initiate with `2`):

```
mysql> SET @id = 2;                                                              
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                                             

mysql> SELECT * FROM Inheritance FORCE KEY (id) WHERE id = (@id := @id+1) ORDER BY id ASC;                                                                        
+-------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-------+               
| classNS     | class             | super      | superNS | id    |               
+-------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-------+               
|             | SocialNetworkLink | Data       |         | 00011 |               
|             | Password          | Data       |         | 00012 |               
|             | User              | Thing      |         | 00013 |               
|             | Asset             | Thing      |         | 00014 |               
|             | Collection        | Asset      |         | 00015 |               
|             | Product           | Asset      |         | 00016 |               
| collections | School            | Collection |         | 00017 |               
| collections | LangSchool        | Collection |         | 00018 |               
+-------------+-------------------+------------+---------+-------+               
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)                                                         

mysql> SELECT @id;                                                               
+------+                                                                         
| @id  |                                                                         
+------+                                                                         
|   25 |                                                                         
+------+                                                                         
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: *I don't know is reliable or not* The variable was initialized, so it is reliable if you guarantee that the query is executed in the same connection. If not, you must init the variable in fake table in FROM section, like `FROM table_name, (SELECT @id := 5) dummy`. *why I can't write WHERE clause like below* If so you will compare id with the @id after re-assign, whereas in present state you compare id with the @id before re-assign.

Comment: **PS.** Try to add `id > 5` condition (not > @id !) to the WHERE section. It can increase the performance, especially when @id is far from start.

Comment: @Akina; Thanks for your explanation about reliability and performance tip. About another note: Yes, *I will compare `id` with `@id` after re-assign*. I think the process should be: *`@id` will be `6` and then the comparison is done. Then `@id` will be `7` and then the comparison is done.  And so on ...*. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_name t1, table_name t2, (SELECT @id := 5) dummy
WHERE t1.id > @id
  AND t1.id = t2.id + 1;
```

If it is possible that the "specific id" may be absent in the table, alter the last condition as

```
  AND t1.id = COALESCE(t2.id, @id) + 1
```

PS. The [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219585/150107) which uses variables seems to be more safe.